# php echo will not display until mail function complete

Tags: php, echo

I cannot get the  this echo (below) to display right away.  It will display only after the mail function complete.  I try using ob_start ob_flush nothing seem to work. When I put exit; before the mail function, the echo display with no delay. Any suggestions on how to have the echo display with on delay would be appreicated

```
echo '<div style=\'margin-top: 10px; margin-left:2px; border: 5px groove blue; border=radius:5px;     padding-left: 10px; width:400px;\'>
 <p>Thanks By <a href="http://www.anyname.com">XXX Martial Art</a></p>
 <hr style=\'margin: 1px auto 1px auto; height: 1px; color: #fefefe; width: 82%;\'/>    
 <h1>Thanks for Your Message! <br>Your message has been sent!  </h1>
 <p><a href="Default.html">Click to go to Home page!</a></p>
 </div>';

<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
$name = trim(stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($_POST['name'])));
$email = trim(stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($_POST['email'])));
$message = trim(stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']))); 
$mailTo = "anyname@yahoo.com";
$msgSubject = "Requesting Information ";
$msgBody = "From:  $name,\n\r Email:  $email,\n\r Message:\n\r$message";
/*$xHeaders = "From: $email X-Mailer: PHP/". phpversion(); */
$xHeaders = "From: $email" . phpversion();

if ($_POST['name'] == "" || $_POST['email'] == "" || $_POST['message'] == ""){
echo "You forgot to enter data in all the field<br>Please enter the data and then submit again";
exit;}

echo '<div style=\'margin-top: 10px; margin-left:2px; border: 5px groove blue; border=radius:5px;     padding-left: 10px; width:400px;\'>
 <p>Thanks By <a href="http://www.anyname.com">XXX Martial Art</a></p>
 <hr style=\'margin: 1px auto 1px auto; height: 1px; color: #fefefe; width: 82%;\'/>    
 <h1>Thanks for Your Message! <br>Your message has been sent!  </h1>
 <p><a href="Default.html">Click to go to Home page!</a></p>
 </div>';

mail($mailTo, $msgSubject, $msgBody, $xHeaders);

$mailTo = $email;
$msgSubject = "Thank You for your email.";
$msgBody = "Thank you for your email. I will respond to you as soon as possible.\n\r
Please feel free to contact me at (818)111-1111 you need immediate assitance.\n\r Our hours are  Monday-Friday 3pm-7:45pm and Saturday 11am-2pm.\n\r
You are alway welcome to drop by during these hours to check out my classes.\n\r\n\r Thank You\n\r Master Lee";
$xHeaders = "From: anyname@yahoo.com". phpversion();
mail($mailTo, $msgSubject, $msgBody, $xHeaders);
echo '<script type="text/javascript">clearform()</script>';

}

?>
```

Comment: That's how it works - PHP is server side, so it will wait until the script has finished processing before it sends the response to the client. If you want to display the message, you should put the actual mail send function into a sort of spooler or queue.

Comment: how long is mail() taking? i have never seen this so slow that it was an issue

Comment: you could do a trick calling an ajax after the page load just to send the emaii.

Comment: @Neto - a suggestion I considered too. Probably the easiest approach overall although you'd need to do something with sessions to prevent spamming on the server side as all the data would be visible to the client and would be easy enough to call again and again

Comment: @Neto could you give me an example of calling an ajax

Comment: @user3634733 look at this exemple: http://jsbin.com/yuguhuya/1/
but there is a problem, you will display a success message before the email script fires, and if it fails what will you do?